# How can I assign sentiment score based on sentiment label?

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

I am working on a R project. I used a general inquirer dictionary- a dictionary that has several sentiment lexicons. I downloaded it from here http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~inquirer/inquirerbasic.xls

Now, I want to create a new column "score" that will assign a value say 1 if the value Positive is available

```
df <- read.csv("inquirerbasics.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3 <- subset(df, select=c(1:6))
head(df3)

 Entry Source Positiv Negativ Pstv Affil
1           A  H4Lvd                           
2     ABANDON  H4Lvd         Negativ           
3 ABANDONMENT     H4         Negativ           
4       ABATE  H4Lvd         Negativ           
5   ABATEMENT    Lvd                           
6    ABDICATE     H4         Negativ
```

Now I want to create a column score, where I can assign score of 1 for Negativ values,  for Positiv values, 3 for Pstv and son on? How do I create this?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to create a `key/val` dataset and join with the original dataset after creating a single column using `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
keyval <- data.frame(key = c("Negativ", "Positiv", "Pstv"),
             score = c(1, 1, 3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df3 %>%
    mutate(key = coalesce(Positiv, Negativ, Pstv)) %>% 
    left_join(., keyval) %>%
    select(-key)
# Joining, by = "key"
# A tibble: 11,788 x 7
#         Entry Source Positiv Negativ  Pstv Affil score
#         <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
# 1           A  H4Lvd    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    NA
# 2     ABANDON  H4Lvd    <NA> Negativ  <NA>  <NA>     1
# 3 ABANDONMENT     H4    <NA> Negativ  <NA>  <NA>     1
# 4       ABATE  H4Lvd    <NA> Negativ  <NA>  <NA>     1
# 5   ABATEMENT    Lvd    <NA>    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    NA
# 6    ABDICATE     H4    <NA> Negativ  <NA>  <NA>     1
# 7       ABHOR     H4    <NA> Negativ  <NA>  <NA>     1
# 8       ABIDE     H4 Positiv    <NA>  <NA> Affil     1
# 9     ABILITY  H4Lvd Positiv    <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     1
#10      ABJECT     H4    <NA> Negativ  <NA>  <NA>     1
# ... with 11,778 more rows
```

NOTE: Here, we used only the first 6 columns based on the example showed in the OP's post.  If we need more columns, change the 'keyval' to add the 'key' and 'score' for those columns, `coalesce` all those columns before joining

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with dictionaries, I recommend our text mining package [**quanteda**](http://quanteda.io), which has extensive functions for working with dictionaries.

It allows fixed, "glob", or regular expression matches to dictionary values, which is really useful since many text dictionary schemes use globs as wildcards.

Here's how I would do it.

```
library("quanteda")
packageVersion("quanteda")
## [1] ‘0.99.9’

geninquirer <- df

# construct a quanteda dictionary
# also cleans up the #1 etc tags
GIpos <- 
    c(geninquirer$Entry[geninquirer$Positiv == "Positiv"], 
      geninquirer$Entry[geninquirer$Yes == "Yes"]) %>%
    stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("#\\w+$", "") %>%
    unique
GIneg <- 
    c(geninquirer$Entry[geninquirer$Negativ == "Negativ"],
      geninquirer$Entry[geninquirer$No == "No"]) %>%
    stringi::stri_replace_all_regex("#\\w+$", "") %>%
    unique
GI_dict <- dictionary(list(positive = GIpos, negative = GIneg))

txt <- "I will abandon other text analysis packages for dictionary
        analyis because the excellent quanteda makes it so easy."
```

While you can do this in one step, here I've created the dfm first, and applied the dictionary to it in a second step.

```
dfm(txt) %>% dfm_lookup(dictionary = GI_dict, nomatch = "other")
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 3 features (0% sparse).
## 1 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
## features
## docs    positive negative other
##   text1        2        1    16
```

Note that you didn't even need to lowercase the dictionary values, since the default for matching is case-insensitive.